# :find cannot find file in 'path' which command-line can see

Tags: find

Suppose the directory tree looks like this:

```
rootdir
├── data
│   └── file.txt
└── data2
    └── file2.txt
```

When Vim is launched at `rootdir` and configured with `:set path=data*`, it is unable to `:find` either file:

```
:find file.txt
E345: Can't find file "file.txt" in path
:find file2.txt
E345: Can't find file "file2.txt" in path
```

However, if the path is adjusted to `:set path=dat*`, *then* `:find` is able to locate both files.

Could this be a bug in Vim? It only seems to affect file searching ([`:h file-searching`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#file-searching)), rather than wildcard expansion ([`:h wildcards`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#wildcards)), since that command-line tab completion finds both files:

```
:find             <Tab>
:find file.txt    <Tab>
:find file2.txt
```

---

## Issue Variation: `**`

The above example starts half-working when using `**` instead of `*`:

```
:set path=data**
:find file.txt     " Succeeds
:find file2.txt    " Fails
```

---

## Deeper Directory Tree

Now suppose this is the directory tree:

```
rootdir
├── data
│   └── subdir
│       └── file.txt
└── data2
    └── subdir
        └── file2.txt
```

The results of `:find` with different `'path'` values are:

```
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
| 'path'   | :find file.txt | :find file2.txt |
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
| data**   | Succeeds       | Fails           |
| data*/** | Succeeds       | Fails           |
| data*/*  | Fails          | Fails           |
| dat**    | Succeeds       | Succeeds        |
| dat*/**  | Succeeds       | Succeeds        |
| dat*/*   | Succeeds       | Succeeds        |
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
```

---

## Vim Version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 10 2020 04:05:27)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-13
```

Comment: Did you read help file-searching, where it discusses the use and details of `*` and `**`?

Comment: Considering I linked [`:h file-searching`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#file-searching) in the question, I think it gives a strong enough hint. 

Comment: i know; thats why i asked—im having a hard time pinpointing what part of your expectations were based on the documentation, since (if my understanding is correct) some of the examples make a little less sense when compared with those docs

Comment: Based on the docs, it is not clear why `data**` should have an issue matching `data2/` _only if_ `data/` is present. More generally, this is an example where Vim's matching of sibling directory A depends on the presence of directory B, which seems bonkers and smells like a bug.